# How can I send my {todo.id} in a child component to my parent component's handler?

Tags: reactjs

I am able to confirm that my handler is receiving the event, but I want to be able to refer to the actual `key={todo.id}`, (or just the `{todo}`), that my anchor tag is attached to inside the handler, because I want this as a reference to set my state. Can someone please tell me how I would do this?

```
import React from 'react';

const Todo = props => (
    <div>
       <ul className = "list-group">
       {props.todos.map(todo => {
          return <li className = "list-group-item" key ={todo.id}>{todo.text}<a onClick={props.onDelete}
          className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" href="#"></a></li>
         })
        }
       </ul>
    </div>
);

export default Todo;
```

That's the child where you can see `key={todo.id}` as well as the `{props.onDelete}` handler ^^^.

I then have this handler in my parent component, so how can I refer to it inside this handler?:

```
handleDelete(){
    console.log();

  }
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could e.g. create a new inlined arrow function for each todo and pass the `todo` as argument to `onDelete` that way:

```
<a
  onClick={() => props.onDelete(todo)}
  className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"
  href="#"
/>
```

If you don't want to create a new function for each todo in each render, you could put the `todo.id` in a `data` attribute:

```
<a
  onClick={props.onDelete}
  className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"
  href="#"
  data-id={todo.id}
/>

// ...

handleDelete(event) {
  const todoId = event.target.dataset.id;
  console.log(todoId);
}
```

Comment: Hey, @Tholle/ anyone else who reads this later, I take that back. You enabled me to target the id of my anchor tag, but not my actual    `todo`    item. 

I made these adjustments: 

`onClick={() => props.onDelete(todo.id)}`

And then in my handler:

 `handleDelete(id) {
    console.log('delete clicked', id);
  }`

This targeted the actual item's id like i wanted. Cheers.

Comment: @SamuelWarren The first example in my answer passes the todo item to the `onDelete` method, and the second example one passes the id. I thought that was what you wanted.